# How to set an empty string as a default value for a DataSource parameter in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This doesn't work. I've got an exception from SQL databse that column does not allow nulls.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDataSOurcet" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO MyTable(Name) VALUES (@Name) WHERE NameID = 1" 
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" DefaultValue=""/>
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try

```
   <asp:Parameter Name="Name"  Type="string" DefaultValue="" 
    ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
```

But I thought that was default.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDataSOurcet" runat="server" OnInserting="MyDataSOurcetInserting" ... >

//cs
protected void MyDataSOurcetInserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
   //check if nothing has been inserted then
   e.Command.Parameters["Name"].value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it should be rather: e.Command.Parameters["Name"].value = "" for an empty string, right? But the Henk's solution is sufficient for my problem.

Comment: yes you could that but i recommend you to start using null values to store empty string in the database. anyway im glad you managed to solve it!!